# Compare String using if(!"D".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) not working

Tags: java

```
if(!"D".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) || !"W".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)){
         System.out.println("The answer is invalid!Please input again!");
         answer = input.nextLine();
    }else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("D")){
        System.out.println("Enter deposite ammount: ");
        depositAmmount = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("adding %.2f to account1\n\n", depositAmmount);
        acc1.Credit(depositAmmount);

        //display balance
        System.out.format("ballance of account1 is: %.2f\n", acc1.getBallance());
        System.out.format("ballance of account2 is: %.2f\n\n", acc2.getBallance());
    }
    else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("W")){
        System.out.println("Enter withdraw ammount: ");
        withdrawAmmount = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("differing %.2f to account1\n\n", withdrawAmmount);
        acc1.Withdraw(withdrawAmmount);

        //display balance
        System.out.format("ballance of account1 is: %.2f\n", acc1.getBallance());
        System.out.format("ballance of account2 is: %.2f\n", acc2.getBallance());
    }
```

I'm trying to make an simple application with deposit and with draw. But it have a bug when I used `!equals` to make sure user must input `D` or `W` and the others key will input again until input right key but in here it doesn't work and input `D` or `W` it's not recognize inform the input is invalid.

I need some help.

Answer (score 3):

If the answer must be either D or W, the condition should be :

```
if(!("D".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) || "W".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)))
```

or

```
if(!"D".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) && !"W".equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `||` by `&&` in your first line.

You write the error message if the answer is not D or not W. As it cannot be both, you always get the error message.

Comment: First one to notice the mistake however you may want to use formatting in your answers (i.e. `||` and `&&`)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to put

```
if(!"D".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) && !"W".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)){
          // your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[De morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) should really help you, worth reading about it:

```
(not a) OR (not b)  ⟷  not (a AND b)
```

Applying this to your condition:

```
if(!"D".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) || !"W".equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
```

Is the same as:

```
if(!("D".equalsIgnoreCase(answer) && "W".equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
   ↑
 Note that it's applied to the whole expression
```

Which can *never* be `true`.

Solution:

As others already suggested, replace `||` with `&&`.